# Sneak attack experience based on damage or number of hits?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If Sneak experience earned by sneak attacks is based on number of hits, then it may be more efficient to use a weaker weapon.

Is experience gained based on the damage dealt, or number of hits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Successful sneak attacks give the biggest skill increases. Melee sneak attacks give 12x as much as ranged sneak attacks. The amount is flat per sneak attack and does not depend on the damage done.

Source: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak#Skill_Increases).

Comment: Do you know if each hit from each weapons counts, or does one power attack count as one sneak attack?

Comment: @NiteCyper if you're talking about dual-wielding, I believe each strike is counted as a separate attack.

Comment: How many hits does it take to get to the center of a Legendary Sneak skill?